# Sum daily totals plus grand total from multiple tables in MSSQL

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I am relatively new to MS Access SQL within VB6, and looking for an answer I just saw here a question that almost fit what I need (sum daily total by category in MSSQL). But I still can't find out how to implement it in my code, I am pretty sure I am missing some command or order.

This is what I got:

```
    Qry = "SELECT pv_S.Id, Agenda.Company, pv_S.Fecha, Products.Descripción, " _
        & "pv_S.Cant, pv_S.PV, pv_S.Pagado, pv_S.User " _
        & "FROM Products " _
        & "INNER JOIN (Agenda INNER JOIN pv_S " _
        & "ON Agenda.CustomerID = pv_S.CustomerID) " _
        & "ON Products.ProdId = pv_S.ProdId " _
        & "WHERE pv_S.Fecha BETWEEN #" & Format(FromDate, "MM/DD/YYYY") & "# " _
        & "AND #" & Format(ToDate, "MM/DD/YYYY") & "# " _
        & "AND pv_S.User  = '" & cboCombos(2).Text & "' " _
        & "ORDER BY Fecha"
```

This is what I need:

```
Report From: 1/1/17 To: 3/1/17


    FECHA   USER   Cant
    1/1/17   Sam    50
    1/1/17   Sam    60
    1/1/17   Sam    20
             Tot   130

    2/1/17   Sam    80
    2/1/17   Sam    80
             Tot   160

    3/1/17   Sam    50
    3/1/17   Sam    10
    3/1/17   Sam    20
    3/1/17   Sam    70
             Tot   150

             GTot  440
```

What I am doing is horrible, looping through the database is insane. I know there should and must be an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

You say 'sum daily total by category'. What category? Your output example shows 3 fields from pv_S but none from Agenda and Products.

If you want to see details from all 3 tables along with summary calcs, build an Access report. The RecordSource would be a query of the raw data records. Use report Grouping and Sorting design features. Add a group section on whatever field is your 'category'. Put a textbox in group footer and report footer with expression: `=Sum([Cant])`.

Apply date and user filter criteria to the report. I never use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer to build filter criteria with VBA and apply to report when opening. Review [Allen Browne Filter](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html)

If you can't use an Access report, what do you use for reports? Why are you using VB6 instead of VBA behind Access?

A query-only approach to achieve the output arrangement you show would probably involve building two aggregate queries and then a UNION of those to the raw data recordset.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. The 'sum daily total' is a reference to another answer, I did not include the Agenda and Products data sample because of space. I am using access database but my app is entirely made in vb6 so my customers only use the app GUI. I do not know if I can use that VBA thing within VB6... The UNION thing you mentions is probably what I need, I will check the Allen Browne Filter you mentioned. Thank you very much.

Comment: VBA is the programming language packaged with MS Office apps. It is similar to VB6 in syntax and vocabulary, so no, it is not used 'within' VB6. So are you using CrystalReports or some other reporting tool with VB6? I expect you could build report objects in Access and VB6 could manipulate them. But for a multi-user db that would require the reports to be in a split frontend, not in the data tables file.

Comment: I just finished doing some research and VBA is not an option, the Allen Browne Filter is for Access so no; about CR... I always do all of my reports by code, also all my access SQL queries are completely coded within vb6 using ADO/ADOX. But this one got me...